# 2 cancel buttons appear when enabling cancel button for uisearchbar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar, ios8.1

I've come across this issue in my own project and managed to replicate it in a new project.

My project is a simple setup and easy to replicate if you wish. It is as follows:

1. Added TableViewController to storyboard.
2. Added a Searchdisplaycontroller and SearchBar to newly added TableViewController.
3. Embedded it in a navigation controller.
4. Created a Tableviewcontroller class and added two lines of code to the viewDidLoad method.

   ```
   self.searchDisplayController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
   self.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
   ```

[image: 2 cancel buttons for uisearchbar]

As you can see in the screenshot two cancel buttons appear with an unwanted one just below the expected result.

My question is what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you have added both? Search bar and Search bar display controller? You have to use one of this.

Comment: Yes I added the 'Search Bar and Search Display Controller' component from the object library.